# In Entity Framework Get key/id if row exists else insert row and get the key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have the following table

```
TABLE [dbo].[SoftwareItems](
[SoftwareItemId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Type] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
[SoftwareItem] [varchar](100) NOT NULL)
```

What is the most efficient way to get the key of a row if it exists or insert a new row and  return the key of the new row. Below is what I've so far:

```
var ctx = new Entities();
        var si = ctx.SoftwareItems.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SoftwareItem1.Equals(SoftwareItem) && string.Compare(s.Type, SoftwareItemType) == 0);
        if (si != null)
            return si.SoftwareItemId;
        else
        {
            si = new SoftwareItem();
            si.SoftwareItem1 = SoftwareItem;
            si.Type = SoftwareItemType;
            ctx.SoftwareItems.Add(si);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            return si.SoftwareItemId;
        }
```

Comment: Will concurrency be an issue, or will only one client be accessing the underlying persistence at a time?  Your way is fine, but without a TransactionScope, it could be prone to duplicate entries if multiple clients attempt to call your code.

Comment: Good point. Concurrency is an issue, we could end up with two rows with the same data if we have two requests within a very short timespan , but we can live with that for now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight improvement that avoids to load the whole existing object and loads only the key would be:

```
var ctx = new Entities();
int? softwareItemId = ctx.SoftwareItems
    .Where(s => s.SoftwareItem1.Equals(SoftwareItem) &&
                string.Compare(s.Type, SoftwareItemType) == 0)
    .Select(s => (int?)s.SoftwareItemId)
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (softwareItemId.HasValue)
    return softwareItemId.Value;
else
{
    // your original code...
}
```

Comment: Small improvement but improvement nonetheless. Thank you!